# How can I use Azure to send out emails based on a list of schedules in a storage table

Tags: azure, email

In my UI, a user can create a "report email subscription" which is essentially a daily or weekly schedule for receiving a report. They select the Time that they wish to receive the email and the days in which they need it.

This data is then saved to an Azure Table. So each rowKey in the table represents a unique email schedule created by a user.

I'm building a POC and need something that can be triggered as and when a schedule is due. My initial plan was to use an azure function and just run it every hour to check if any schedules are due, but I'm conscious of cost/resource of making that scan.

Using azure functionality, id like to know if there is a service or webhook that could trigger the azure function to run when a schedule is met?

Answer (score 0):

> id like to know if there is a service or webhook that could trigger the azure function to run when a schedule is met?

As an alternative, You can simply use **`Azure Logic apps`** for this and below is the **`design`** :

[image]

**`Get entites (V2) :`**

```
time eq '@{utcNow()}'
```

**`Condition:`**

```
   length(string(body('Get_entities_(V2)')?['value']))  is greater than or equal to 3
```

**`Inside email action:`**

[image]

**`Azure Storage Table data:`**

[image]

**`Output:`**

If schedule time does not match:

[image]

If schedule time match:

[image]

**`Code view:`**

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Condition": {
                "actions": {
                    "Send_an_email_(V2)": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "body": {
                                "Body": "<p>@{body('Get_entities_(V2)')?['value']}</p>",
                                "Importance": "Normal",
                                "Subject": "IMPORTANT",
                                "To": "bojja@micro.com"
                            },
                            "host": {
                                "connection": {
                                    "name": "@parameters('$connections')['office365']['connectionId']"
                                }
                            },
                            "method": "post",
                            "path": "/v2/Mail"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "ApiConnection"
                    }
                },
                "expression": {
                    "and": [
                        {
                            "greaterOrEquals": [
                                "@length(string(body('Get_entities_(V2)')?['value']))",
                                3
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Get_entities_(V2)": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "If"
            },
            "Get_entities_(V2)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azuretables']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/v2/storageAccounts/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('AccountNameFromSettings'))}/tables/@{encodeURIComponent('rithwik')}/entities",
                    "queries": {
                        "$filter": "time eq '@{utcNow()}'"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "Recurrence": {
                "evaluatedRecurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Hour",
                    "interval": 1
                },
                "recurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Hour",
                    "interval": 1
                },
                "type": "Recurrence"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "azuretables": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/b83c1ed3/resourceGroups/vrbojja/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azuretables",
                    "connectionName": "azuretables",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/b83c1ed3/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/eastus/managedApis/azuretables"
                },
                "office365": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/b83c1ed3/resourceGroups/vrbojja/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/office365",
                    "connectionName": "office365",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/b83c1ed3/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/eastus/managedApis/office365"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```